# Asynchronously updating Zabuto Calendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I have Zabuto calendar showing booking dates, but some tours have many dates for the period, and loading them is slow.
I have changed the API to paginate the data, and send a next url if there is more data to load, but I can't see how to get zabuto calendar to update its data once it is displayed, and with Javascript being the ultimate asynchronous programming language, I figured there must be a way the calendar can display and upload data at the same time.

Posts such as this
[How to load data from ajax to zabuto calendar plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937239/how-to-load-data-from-ajax-to-zabuto-calendar-plugin#37937380)
shows how to load the calendar data by ajax call, but not how to continuously upload more data asynchronously while the current calender data is displayed. Other posts indicate that the only way is to reload the entire calendar
[reloading AJAX data for Zabuto Calendar after modal dismissal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864458/reloading-ajax-data-for-zabuto-calendar-after-modal-dismissal). I would prefer an asynchronous way.

The previous developer started to use the Vue framework, So what I have is a Zabuto calendar Vue module

```
<template>
    <div id="my-calendar-a"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import moment from 'moment'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'ZabutoCalendar',
    methods: {
        initialise: function () {
            $('.calendar-month-navigation .glyphicon').click(function () {
                Vue.bus.$emit('calendar-change-month')
            })
        }
    },
    props: ['tour'],
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('cart', [
            'cartItems'
        ]),
        ...mapGetters('calendar', [
            'tourDates'
        ])
    },
    mounted: function () {
        var self = this
        var currentDate = new Date()
        /*
        Use of the thrid party plugin zabuto calendar to
        set up the calendar and check if dates are being clicked
        https://github.com/zabuto/calendar
         */
        var nextUrl = '/api/check-dates?year=' + moment().format('YYYY') + 
                '&month=' + moment().format('M') + '&tour=' + self.tour;
        this.$store.dispatch('calendar/getTourDates', nextUrl).then(response => {
            // I tried putting a while nextUrl loop here, but the calender wont display till dispatch returns
            nextUrl = self.tourDates[1].next_url;
            $(self.$el).zabuto_calendar({
                data: self.tourDates[0].tourdates,
                weekstartson: 0,
                show_previous: false,
                year: currentDate.getFullYear(),
                month: currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                action: function () {
                    if ($(this).find('> div').hasClass('start_spots')) {
                        // reconstruct data
                        var selectedTour = {}
                        var id = this.id
                        var elem = $('#' + id)

                        $('.calendar-dow .selected').removeClass('selected')
                        $(this).find('> div').addClass('selected')

                        selectedTour = _.find(self.tourDates[0].tourdates, { 'tour_date_id': elem.data('tour_date_id') })

                        selectedTour['styled_date'] = moment(elem.data('date')).format('Do MMMM YYYY')

                        if ($(this).find('> div').hasClass('start_future')) {
                            selectedTour['available'] = 1
                            for (var index in self.cartItems) {
                                if (self.cartItems[index].date === elem.data('date')) {
                                    selectedTour['available'] = 3
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            selectedTour['available'] = 2
                        }

                        self.$store.commit('calendar/setSelectedTour', selectedTour)
                        Vue.bus.$emit('date-click')
                    }
                }
            })
            // while loop could surround above code
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

And a javascript module to do the ajax call to get *all* the data in one go

```
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment'

export const calendar_module = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        tourDates: [],
        selectedTour: {}
    },
    getters: {
        tourDates: (state) => {
            return state.tourDates
        },
        selectedTour: (state) => {
            return state.selectedTour
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setSelectedTour (state, selectedTour) {
            state.selectedTour = selectedTour
        },
        setTourDates (state, tourDates) {
            state.tourDates = tourDates
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getTourDates ({ commit }, datesUrl) {
            var response_data = axios.get(datesUrl).then((response) => {
                commit('setTourDates', response.data)
            });
            return response_data;
        }
    }
}
```

The API response data is returned in the form

```
{ 'tourdates': array_data_object, 'next_url', url_string }
```

with next_url (within the response) set to an empty string if there is no more data. getTourDates actually returns the API response. I tried putting a `while nextUrl` loop around the code where commented, but zabuto calendar does not display till the dispatch function returns.

Does Zabuto Calendar have a built in way to asynchronously update its data while displaying? Otherwise how else can I get it to asynchronously display and load future dates?

Another way would be to get the ajax call to run several concurrently, and just return null in any that are redundant, but I would prefer to query the database first to see how many pages are needed, and would prefer not to waste an ajax call just to find out how many asynchronous hits are needed to get all data.

Comment: Just to note that if I put a while loop to enclose this.$store.dispatch, the script brings the host computer to its knees with a HUGE memory leak, even if the loop is terminated by a counter.

Comment: I think one solution for asynchronous calls would be to use axios.all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not put in a while nextUrl loop, so tried axios.all() instead, which allows for asynchronous calling of multiple gets at the same time. This made no improvement of load time, which was probably just as well, because it forced me to look at my REST API which had several inefficiencies that I would not have otherwise cleaned up.

This is my Async solution (which I no longer needed to use once the API was nice and quick) for posterity

```
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment'

export const calendar_module = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        tourDates: [],
        selectedTour: {}
    },
    getters: {
        tourDates: (state) => {
            return state.tourDates
        },
        selectedTour: (state) => {
            return state.selectedTour
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setSelectedTour (state, selectedTour) {
            state.selectedTour = selectedTour
        },
        setTourDates (state, tourDates) {
            if (state.tourDates.length == 0) {
                state.tourDates = tourDates[0].tourdates;
            } else {
                state.tourDates = state.tourDates.concat(tourDates[0].tourdates);
            }
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getTourDates ({ commit }, datesUrl) {
            var response_data = axios.all([
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=1'),
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=2'),
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=3'),
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=4'),
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=5'),
                axios.get(datesUrl + '&page=6')
                ]).then(axios.spread(function (response1, response2, response3, response4, response5, response6) {
                commit('setTourDates', response1.data);
                commit('setTourDates', response2.data);
                commit('setTourDates', response3.data);
                commit('setTourDates', response4.data);
                commit('setTourDates', response5.data);
                commit('setTourDates', response6.data)
            }));
            return response_data;
        }
    }
}
```